# I am getting extra x value in array object using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, charts

I am actually trying to display `canvas.js` chart using this json dynamically.

I have this result:

```
[{"s":40,"ProductName":"yoga pants"},
{"s":20,"ProductName":"trousers"},{"s":16,"ProductName":"shirts"},
{"s":10,"ProductName":"pants"},{"s":7,"ProductName":"RED"},
{"s":5,"ProductName":"Tank Top"}]
```

…which is a json string

I am getting this:

```
[{40: "yoga pants", x: 0},
{20: "trousers", x: 1},
{16: "shirts", x: 2},
{10: "pants", x: 3},
{7: "RED", x: 4},
{5: "Tank Top", x: 5}]
```

But i do not want this extra `x:` value. I am using this code:

```
var result1 = JSON.parse(result);
var reformattedArray = result1.map(function (o) 
{ 
  var obj = {}; 
  obj[o.s] = o.ProductName;
  return obj; 
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Code shown won't set a property `x` on the mapped objects

Comment: You say "I have this result" and "I am getting this" - is the first one your *input* and the second one the incorrect *output*, where actually you want output like that except without the `x` property? The code shown won't add that `x` property.

Comment: This problem is not reproducible with the code you are showing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that what is really happening is that your reformattedArray is fine, but you are ***subsequently*** piping it through charting software that is assigning the x: property, effectively indexing your data for the x axis of a chart.

Is it possible that the result you are reporting is not the result of your map, but rather the result of an additional step?